# How to Initialize Context on DummyData class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to ask something about a problem of my project which I can't initialize a context from dummyData class. Here's my code.

in Constructor of DummyData :
static Context context;

and i call on method getData() like :

```
VoucherDatabase vd = new VoucherDatabase(context);
ArrayList<VoucherDataModel> voucher = new ArrayList<>();
VoucherDataModel voucherDataModel = new VoucherDataModel();
voucherDataModel.setDesc_discount(vd.getVoucherName());
voucherDataModel.setDesc_discount(vd.getVoucherDesc());
voucherDataModel.setValid_discount(vd.getVoucherValid());
voucher.add(voucherDataModel);
```

but it's finally when i'll try a twice times, i have issue like this.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory,
>   android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

about my insertData from VoucherDatabase like this

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_VOUCHERNAME,voucher_name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_VOUCHERDESC,voucher_desc);
    initialValues.put(KEY_VOUCHERVALID,voucher_valid);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,initialValues);
```

and i have insert into sqlite which like this

```
"CREATE TABLE user_shop_voucher (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, "
+ "voucher_name TEXT NOT NULL, voucher_desc TEXT NOT NULL, voucher_valid TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Please be more specific, and you need to open your database before accessing it.

Comment: Can you please share the code you have written in creating DB or inserting data?